# Error running a python3 script on new Raspberry Pi5

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

When I use this:

```
import board
```

inside a python script running on new Raspberry Pi5, I receive this error:

```
    ImportError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/test_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/board.py", line 50, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.board.raspberrypi.raspi_5b import *
  File "/home/user/test_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/board/raspberrypi/raspi_5b.py", line 6, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.bcm2712 import pin
  File "/home/user/test_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/bcm2712/pin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.libgpiod_pin import Pin
  File "/home/user/test_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/libgpiod_pin.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: libgpiod Python bindings not found, please install and try again! See https://github.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/blob/main/libgpiod.py
```

Any idea?

P.S. the same script woks without issue on RPi 3

Comment: "board" is Adafruit module for rpi3, not for Rpi5.

Comment: @tlfong01 Hi. Thanks for your reply. Do you know any workaround ?

Comment: Rpi5 must use "libgpiod" which again is not compatible to Rpi5. In other words, you must use "libgpiod".